# Permission setting, best practice for website?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, permissions

What permissions is it advised to set my website at?

I know 777 is a bad idea, but what should it actually be?

Comment: In principle you only need read permissions for the WWW group and others.  Unlikely you will need execution privilege so I would say 644 is what you need for the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle you only need read permissions for the WWW group and others. Unlikely you will need execution privilege so I would say 644 is what you need for the files